# Find two integers such that |m+ αn + β| < ε

Tags: number-theory, manifolds

An assignment I am working on (Problem 4-4 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*) reduces to the following problem. Given $\alpha, \beta, \varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, with $\alpha$ irrational and $\varepsilon > 0$, show there exist two integers, $m, n$ such that $$|m - \alpha \cdot n + \beta| < \epsilon.$$

If $\beta\in \mathbb{Z}$, then we could simply use [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), but I've not been able to prove it in general.

One thing I've tried is approximating $\beta$ as a rational number $\tilde \beta = p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$, which leads to $|m - \alpha n + p/q | < \epsilon$ which can be manipulated into $|qm + p - \alpha q n | < \epsilon$. We can then let $\tilde m = qm + p$ and $\tilde n = q n$, and apply DAT to show $\tilde m$ and $\tilde n$ exist such that $|\tilde m + \alpha \tilde n| < q\epsilon$. One problem with this approach, though, is that when we solve for $m = \frac{\tilde m - p}{q}$ we aren't guaranteed to get an integer.

Comment: Search for Kronecker's density theorem. You only need the 1-dimensional case. The proof is pretty much the same as with Dirichlet's. You can find integers $m,n$ such that the fractional part of $m-n\alpha$ is in $(0,\epsilon)$. But then $2m-2n\alpha,3m-3n\alpha,\ldots$ make a sequence with increments less than $\epsilon$. Surely you can approximate anything in $(0,1)$ well enough with one of those.

Comment: Wow, that's oddly specific to what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it looks like that does not apply. Using the notation from the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem), the condition only holds if $\beta r \in \mathbb{Z}$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is impossible if $\beta$ is irrational.

Comment: That WP-page looks very weird to me. The version of Kronecker's density theorm I know of says that if the set $1,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ of real numbers is linearly independent over $\Bbb{Z}$ (in particular all the $\alpha_i$ are irrational), then the fractional parts of the vectors $m(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ are dense in $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: I don't really understand French, but here [the French WP-page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Kronecker_(approximation_diophantienne)) (linked to in the one you found) seems to accurately describe the content of the theorem. Looks like some twit edited the English edition. Anyway, the theorem is on many number theory texts, and my first comment is a proof in the 1-dimensional case.

Comment: Mind you the Finnish WP-page linked to in that page is even more off :-)

Comment: On Wolfram MathWorld, the theorem is stated in exactly the form I need. Thanks! http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Jyrki Lahtonen in the comments above, we can use Kronecker's Approximation Theorem, which, according to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html), is as follows for the one-dimensional case.

For any $\alpha, \beta, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, with $\alpha$ irrational and $\epsilon > 0$, then there exists integers $m$ and $n$ with $n>0$, such that 
$$|m - \alpha n + \beta| < \epsilon.$$